# Garbled subject line in Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, email, outlook, lotus-notes, lotus

My C# app sends e-mail messages to the user. One of my users is in Japan and he uses Lotus Notes (v8.5.1). He reports that the e-mail subject line contains garbled text. When I send this same message to my own e-mail client (Outlook Express) the subject line renders fine. Also Gmail renders the text correctly.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem? Below follows the complete e-mail message:

```
X-ASG-Debug-ID: 1328001534-0391c50bb713ff80001-npAiWI
Received: from server46.mailservera.nl (server46.mailservera.nl [93.94.226.162]) by barracuda.klm.nl with ESMTP id jSYJ8WPeN4GeDrLN for <pdamster@klm.nl>; Tue, 31 Jan 2012 10:18:54 +0100 (CET)
X-Barracuda-Envelope-From: klmsemin@server46.mailservera.nl
X-ASG-Whitelist: Sender
X-Barracuda-Apparent-Source-IP: 93.94.226.162
Received: from server46.mailservera.nl (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by server46.mailservera.nl (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.4) with ESMTP id q0V9IrPk014369
    (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA bits=256 verify=NOT)
    for <pdamster@klm.nl>; Tue, 31 Jan 2012 10:18:54 +0100
Received: (from klmsemin@localhost)
    by server46.mailservera.nl (8.14.3/8.14.3/Submit) id q0V9IrCV014353;
    Tue, 31 Jan 2012 10:18:53 +0100
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2012 10:18:53 +0100
Message-Id: <201201310918.q0V9IrCV014353@server46.mailservera.nl>
To: pdamster@klm.nl
Subject: InfoSys認証コードのリクエスト
From: pdamster@klm.nl
X-ASG-Orig-Subj: InfoSys認証コードのリクエスト
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Virus-Scanned: by amavisd-new
X-Barracuda-Connect: server46.mailservera.nl[93.94.226.162]
X-Barracuda-Start-Time: 1328001534
X-Barracuda-URL: http://10.0.0.8:8000/cgi-mod/mark.cgi
X-Barracuda-Orig-Rcpt: pdamster@klm.nl
X-Virus-Scanned: by bsmtpd at klm.nl

リクエストいただいた内容は以下の通りです。コンピュータコード: 43C3-427F-4457-35F6-3F0D<br><br>施設名 : KLM<br>得意先コード : 12345<br>担当者 : 11<br>住所 : 111<br>郵便番号 / 市 : 1 111<br>電話番号 : 1<br>メールアドレス : pdamster@klm.nl<br>
```

Comment: Garbled text as in the Japanese characters not being shown correct? It's probably related to a charset issue (you currently use UTF-8 and perhaps you need to use a charset that supports Japanese characters).

Comment: UTF-8 does support Japanese characters, but you cannot directly send UTF-8 in an email header.  You have to use a special encoding format as specified in the RFC that Martin pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

Since [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), conforming message header names and values should be ASCII characters; **values that contain non-ASCII data should use the MIME encoded-word syntax** ([RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047))
The form is: "=?charset?encoding?encoded text?=".

For example,
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1Hola,_se=F1or!?=

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

Comment: ISO 8859-1 cannot represent Japanese characters.

Since he is using UTF-8 for the content, I would suggest using base64-encoding it, and using "Subject: =?UTF-8?B?=<base64 data goes here>?="